# Mapping control statements/keywords to a dictionary or other structure in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword, control-flow

This question might be hard to frame correctly. But the essence of the question is: Is it possible to put python control statements such as `break`, `return` and `continue` into a dictionary for later use?

Why would anyone in their right mind want to do this you might ask? Well imagine you're writing the interpreter of a computer programming language. You're traversing an abstract syntax tree and at a leaf you encounter a break statement. Now to implement this you might throw an exception at the leaf to be cought at the loop interior node of the AST. The interior node implements a while loop in python which represents a loop in the code you're interpreting.

So what you want to do is to reduce this code:

```py
def visitWhileStatement(self, ctx):
    while ctx.children[2].accept(self):
        try:
            ctx.children[4].accept(self)
        except LoopControl as lc:
            if lc.value == "break":
                break
            if lc.value == "continue":
                continue
```

Into something which looks a bit more like:

```py
def visitWhileStatement(self, ctx):
    while ctx.children[2].accept(self):
        try:
            ctx.children[4].accept(self)
        except LoopControl as lc:
            LoopControl.actions[lc.value]
```

Like you can do when you map operators like `==` to a function through a dictionary:

```py
self.operators = { "===": lambda x, y: type(x) == type(y) and x == y }
```

I'd like to map `break` to the python control statement:

```py
LoopControl.actions = { "break": break }
```

Except that doesn't work of course.

The motivation behind such a dictionary is to reduce the amount of duplicated code. The code would then appear only once in LoopControl instead of as a series of if-statements in the implementation of every type of breakable loop of the language you're implementing.

Comment: Maybe you could use `exec`? https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement For example `a = {'break': 'break'}` and then `exec(a['break'])`
`

Comment: No, you can't store [keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in a dictionary; they aren't objects. You could subclass the `LoopControl` exception to `LoopControlBreak` and `LoopControlContinue`, save a few lines that way.

Comment: Instead of writing an interpreter for a custom language, write a tool to automatically convert it to a Python or C++ code, run, and take the results.

Comment: @MykhayloKopytonenko It's an exercise in writing interpreters.

Comment: @Marein This does not seem to work as, at least in Python 3.4, exec seems to create it's own context. I get a SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
when I try this solution.

Comment: You're right, I should have tested more thoroughly.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to reduce LOC here at all except for the obvious in-lining of break and continue statements and semicolon BS. Even with further subclassed exceptions, you're going to have to branch on their type eventually. If you *really* want to reduce LOC, trash the while loop and use a recursive function instead. That gives you a bit more power, I think. `continue` is `return {recursive call}`, and `break` is `return None`